# Sum of Pairs: Codewars

Tags: python

I recently solved a problem as stated below in Codewars(**NOT** asking for a solution, already solved it) and though it is not the optimized solution I came across a very interesting problem which I could not figure out an answer to.

**I have NO intention to give out the solution, but just understand what happened that resulted in this anomaly**

The problem ran as - Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up to form the sum.

Pretty simple problem and a straightforward if not optimum solution that I came up with -

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    indices = []
    for i in ints:
        if (s-i) in ints[ints.index(i)+1:]:
            print(ints.index(i))
            print(ints[ints.index(i)+1:])
            print(i,s-i)
            indices.append([ints.index(i),ints[ints.index(i)+1:].index(s-i)+len(ints[:ints.index(i)])+1])
    if(len(indices) == 0):
        return None
    print(indices)
    indices.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(indices)
    return [ints[indices[0][0]], ints[indices[0][1]]]
```

I passed all the test-cases.

I made use of the print statements for debugging and figuring out what was going on. Sample test cases and their output which stumped me are given below.

```
sum_pairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 2)

0
[2, 3, 4, 1, 0]
(1, 1)
1
[3, 4, 1, 0]
(2, 0)
0
[2, 3, 4, 1, 0]
(1, 1)
[[0, 4], [1, 5], [0, 4]]
[[0, 4], [0, 4], [1, 5]]

sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5])
1
[2, 3, 7, 5]
(5, 5)
3
[7, 5]
(3, 7)
1
[2, 3, 7, 5]
(5, 5)
[[1, 5], [3, 4], [1, 5]]
[[3, 4], [1, 5], [1, 5]]
```

So now to the part that I could not figure out, observing the output one can see that in test case 1, 0 is printed twice and the ints[ints.index(i)+1:] is [2, 3, 4, 1, 0] for both 1's at position 0 and 4 and the entry [0,4] is appended twice.
A similar pattern is observed in test case 2.
The if condition which says

```
if (s-i) in ints[ints.index(i)+1:]
```

should not be evaluated to true the second time as ints[ints.index(i)+1:] is there to ensure that the new list starts from the item next to the occurrence of i.

It seems not that important as I got the solution but it would be great if someone can shed light on what actually happened.

**NOTE**: I have had 2 bad experiences where people downvoted my question without giving a reason to do so in a predefined ratio. It would be really useful if I could be given feedback for any such downvote, also would appreciate if anyone could check those questions and give feedback if any improvements can be made.

Comment: Are you expecting `ints.index(i)` to be the index of the particular occurrence of `i` you're working with? You want `enumerate` for that. `index` does something completely different.

Comment: This is not the final solution and I need to optimize for timeout and this information is independent of the problem I posed.

Comment: Hi @user2357112 thanks for the quick reply, I was not aware of this information. My understanding was that index(i) would return the index of the current item. I now understand what is going on. I do not know how to close the question and cannot mark up your answer since I do not have enough reputation. Thank you though!

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question.  Is this not the case?  If you're trying to honourably retire it, we'll need @user2357112 to write up the answer -- it's only a comment right now.

Comment: OK that works, if this might help someone I do not want to delete it, also I would upvote @user2357112 's answer but I do not have the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ints.index(i)` doesn't give you the index of the particular occurrence of `i` you're working with. If you want that, you want `enumerate`, not `index`.

`ints.index(i)` means "go through `ints` and find the index of the *first* element of `ints` that equals `i`". `i` holds no information about where in `ints` it came from, so there's no way for `index` to tell that you were thinking of any particular occurrence of `i`. `enumerate` avoids this problem by keeping its own counter and incrementing it every time it produces an element, so it always knows what index it's at.